# AWSのWindowsServerのEC2インスタンスにリモートデスクトップ接続ができなくなる問題

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2, rdp

AmazonWebServiceのEC2インスタンスでWindowsServer(Micro2の無料版)を作成し、そこにリモートデスクトップ接続をして使用しているのですが、今まで使用していたPCとは別のクライアントPCからRDPしようとすると、
接続することができなくなってしまいます。
一度この現象が出て、再び今まで接続できていたPCでまた接続しようとすると、同じ現象が出て
接続できなくなってしまいます。

その原因と対策を教えていただけますでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上記のダイアログが出てきてしまい、ログイン情報の入力にも進みません。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

インスタンスに付与したセキュリティグループで、リモートデスクトップ (RDP) のアクセス許可を行っているかを確認してみてください。

[リモートデスクトップからリモートコンピュータに接続できません](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/troubleshoot-connect-windows-instance.html)

> - セキュリティグループに、RDP アクセスを許可するルールがあることを確認します。詳細については、「[セキュリティグループの作成](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/get-set-up-for-amazon-ec2.html#create-a-base-security-group)」を参照してください。